# Selecting From 2 Different Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

sql version : '5.7.34'

as the below :

First Table Name  : `Invoice`

table invoice description

| column name | type name | extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| invoicenumber | int(11) | AI PK |
| item_number | char(255) |  |
| description | char(255) |  |
| qty | decimal(9,2) |  |

Items Table Description :

| column name | type name | extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | int(11) | AI PK |
| item_number | varchar(255) | PK |
| Item_Desc | varchar(255) |  |
| Start_Balance | decimal(9,2) |  |

The Invoice Table have these fields :

```
ItemNumber ,InvoiceNumber ,  Item_Desc , Qty
```

The Items Table have these fields :

```
ItemNumber , Item_Desc, Start_Balance
```

The PrimaryKey for Invoice is invoicenumber

The PrimaryKey for Items Table is Item_Number

So basically what am trying to do is get the remaining quantity by getting Start_balance from items table and Subtract it from the total qty of each item order in the invoice table based on item number .

The Invoice table can have multiple records with item number while the items table only have unique item number for each row .

How do I make select statement to join both table to get the remaining qty for each itemNumber by joining both tables ?

I tried this:

```
    (SELECT 
        `items`.`Start_Balance_Qty` - SUM(`invoice`.`QTY`)) AS `currentitembalance`,
        `details`.`item_number` AS `itemnumber`,
        `details`.`DESCRIPTION` AS `itemdesc`,
        `items`.`item_number` AS `item_number`
    FROM
    (`items`
    JOIN `invoice`)
    WHERE

       (`invoice`.`item_number` = `items`.`item_number`)
       GROUP BY `items`.`item_number`)
```

Its working fine , but the problem it's only getting the records on invoice table  which match itemNumber in both table, I need to display all the fields in the items table to show current balance , in other words , I want the result to display the remaining qty of the items table despite how many records are matched in the invoice table.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL 5.6` version? If you use `group by` , the selected columns must be in the `group by` or part of an aggregation function. Please add table description, some data and your expected result ?

Comment: ok i will add expected result soon

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to make sure all rows in the leading table are returned in the result set, even if it does not match any record in the joining table, append joining condition at `ON` clause instead of `WHERE` clause. When `SUM` values, convert `NULL` to `0`

```
SELECT 
a.item_number AS itemnumber, 
MAX(a.description) AS itemdesc, 
MAX(a.start_balance_qty) - SUM(IFNULL(b.qty, 0))
FROM items a
LEFT JOIN invoice b ON a.item_number = b.item_number
GROUP BY a.item_number
;
```